# If the applyRefPoint is set to true, the text markup disappears once the text is typed

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, markup, forge

Text markups are not showing if applyRefPoint is set as True

If the applyRefPoint is set to true, the text markup disappears once the text is typed. However, if it is set to false, there are no problems. Provided below is the code for your reference.

[image: Viewer3DjsandCss]

Model Loading:

[image: Model Loading]

For enabling markup

[image: For enabling markup]

If applyRefPoint is true:

[image: If applyRefPoint is true:]

If applyRefPoint is false:
[image: If applyRefPoint is false:]

Please help!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I just tried reproducing this using the following code snippet:

```js
function loadModel(viewer, urn, options) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
            'urn:' + urn,
            (doc) => resolve(viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry(), options)),
            (code, msg, errors) => reject(code, msg, errors)
        );
    });
}

Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer({ accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN }, async function () {
    const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('preview'));
    viewer.start();
    await loadModel(viewer, MODEL_URN, { applyRefPoint: true, isAEC: true });
    const markupsExt = await viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore');
    markupsExt.enterEditMode();
    const text = new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.EditModeText(markupsExt);
    markupsExt.changeEditMode(text);
});
```

But the text markup stays visible as expected:

[image]

So this could potentially be some issue specific to your design file. If you could share it with us via `aps (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` (confidentially - the file would not be shared with anyone outside of Autodesk), we'd be happy to investigate it further.

EDIT:

For anyone who might be running into the same issue in the future. It looks like there's a problem with browser support for SVG clipping paths. Consider the following two HTML/SVG snippets. Both of them are generated using the Markups extension, and the only difference between is the translation applied to the SVG elements.

### Good SVG

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" layer-order-id="markups-svg"
        style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; transform:scale(1,-1); -ms-transform:scale(1,-1); -webkit-transform:scale(1,-1); -moz-transform:scale(1,-1); -o-transform:scale(1,-1); transformOrigin:0, 0; -ms-transformOrigin:0, 0; -webkit-transformOrigin:0, 0; -moz-transformOrigin:0, 0; -o-transformOrigin:0, 0; "
        width="865" height="958" viewBox="-608.267427004187 -649.698277842789 1097.4372 1215.4277"
        pointer-events="painted" cursor="crosshair">
        <g cursor="default">
            <g cursor="default" pointer-events="painted" style="display: block;">
                <g clip-path="url(#markup-clipper)">
                    <clipPath id="markup-clipper">
                        <rect transform="translate( 62.88209424768695 , 112.7986355668694 ) rotate( 0 ) scale(1,-1)"
                            x="0" y="0" width="190.3070" height="29.1804"></rect>
                    </clipPath>
                    <text id="markup" alignment-baseline="middle" font-family="Arial" font-size="12.6871"
                        fill="rgba(255,0,0,1)" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal"
                        transform="translate( 62.88209424768695 , 100.11149889558567 ) rotate( 0 ) scale(1,-1)">
                        <tspan x="6.3435" y="6.3435">Test</tspan>
                    </text>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>
```

### Bad SVG

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" layer-order-id="markups-svg"
        style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; transform:scale(1,-1); -ms-transform:scale(1,-1); -webkit-transform:scale(1,-1); -moz-transform:scale(1,-1); -o-transform:scale(1,-1); transformOrigin:0, 0; -ms-transformOrigin:0, 0; -webkit-transformOrigin:0, 0; -moz-transformOrigin:0, 0; -o-transformOrigin:0, 0; "
        width="865" height="958" viewBox="10681277.278292915 138282.259185635 1097.4372 1215.4277"
        pointer-events="painted" cursor="crosshair">
        <g cursor="default">
            <g cursor="default" pointer-events="painted" style="display: block;">
                <g clip-path="url(#markup-clipper)">
                    <clipPath id="markup-clipper">
                        <rect transform="translate( 10681946.136471232 , 139014.09640968058 ) rotate( 0 ) scale(1,-1)"
                            x="0" y="0" width="190.3070" height="29.1804"></rect>
                    </clipPath>
                    <text id="markup" alignment-baseline="middle" font-family="Arial" font-size="12.6871"
                        fill="rgba(255,0,0,1)" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal"
                        transform="translate( 10681946.136471232 , 139001.40927230174 ) rotate( 0 ) scale(1,-1)">
                        <tspan x="6.3435" y="6.3435">Test</tspan>
                    </text>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>
```

In Chrome and Firefox, clipping paths (generated by the Markups extension) with large translation values don't seem to be working as expected - while the clipping path is placed in the exact same area as the text, the text is not visible. And in Safari the same clipping paths work as expected.

Comment: I have shared the RVT file via email. Kindly check and revert.