# Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore extension issue with Revit models that have large Project Base Point

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, revit-api

I'm using Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore extension to add markup to models. But I'm facing an issue with the Revit models that have large Project Base Point.
For example in a model that the Project Base Point is about (8185296, 8185296, 50), for adding dimension there will be a distance between cursor position and the drawn dimension.

[image]
[image]

(However, the original measure tool in Autodesk viewer works completely fine).
[image]

Is there any way to avoid this issue in these models?

**Edit:**
I'm using these options to load models in the viewer:

```js
var modelOptions = {
    sharedPropertyDbPath: doc.getFullPath(
        doc.getRoot().findPropertyDbPath()
    ),
    applyScaling: 'm',
    applyRefPoint: true,
    isAEC: true,
};
viewer.loadModel(
    svfUrl,
    modelOptions,
    onLoadModelSuccess,
    onLoadModelError
);
```

**Edit2:**
After changing the `globalOffset` like [michael beale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77657492/13827956)'s answer, the quality of model reduced extremely:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that this issue occurs when `applyRefPoint` has been set to `true`, like what was said in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76320166/13827956).
So I changed it and everything seems OK.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can force the globalOffset back to zero, to fix the jitter and precision issues you are experiencing.

First check that this is actually the cause, by trying this trick:
[Model aggregating in viewer - coordinate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53764754/model-aggregating-in-viewer-coordinate-issue)

Did that work ?

Comment: Sorry Michael for delay response. Unfortunately, no, it didn't work. Maybe it's not about the global offset, because `viewer.navigation.getPivotPoint()` returns `{ x: 16.36063478717708, y: -17.624643701890434, z: -1.138492243162569 }`. And these are not very large values. 
And also after setting the `globalOffset` in `modelOptions`, the quality of the model reduced extremely. Actually, when I don't set the `globalOffset` the quality is Ok. Either way, though, I have weird markup functions.

Comment: This model has large Project Base Point in Revit (8185296, 8185296, 50). If I'm not wrong,  forge viewer will automatically set global offset to bring model near the origin.